# Why am I getting ThreadWas being aborted

Tags: c#, rest, console-application, webclient

I have a programming running in a loop (Console Application) and it has to upload some file to an API.

This is my code:

```
Using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rm);

     wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
     string myResult = wc.UploadString(URL,serialized);
}
```

This code is within a method and this method is called from time to time, depending on the algorithm processing time. For example, I download some files from a server and then upload to another server with this code above. Then, I download and upload again ...

In the first iteration, this upload method works correctly. However, in the second iteration, it gives me an exception "Thread was being aborted".

I was using HttpClient before, the reason I changed to WebClient is that HttpClient was giving me the same problem.

Can anyone, please, help me with this issue?

The exception stackTrace is:

```
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data)
   at Bizagi.DownloadUpload.UploadHelper.UploadFile(Risk rm, Stopwatch sla) in C:\Users\...\UploadHelper.cs:line 189
   at Bizagi.DownloadUpload.UploadHelper.UploadToRisk(TACTIVE obj, String destination, Stopwatch timerSLA) in C:\Users\...\UploadHelper.cs:line 36
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okr76.png)

Comment: What's the full exception and stack trace? It's probably coming from the server.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the value of `maxRequestLength` and `executionTimeout` in the config?

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya I have not set up any maxRequestLength or executionTimeout in this case. 
But, I am trying to upload the same files all the time.

Comment: @SLaks I updated the question with the stacktrace and fullname.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that my problem wasn't because of this code.

While my code was being executed, there was another thread running. 
I don't know why, but this thread used to stop when computer was executing the code I wrote above (maybe coincidence).

I changed the code that managed the thread and my code started to work like a charm.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help.